# Trying to validate a passed value to a method

Tags: java

I have a program that is trying to validate a passed value. I want a user to input anything and the method that I pass it to will validate whether the input would work.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ChequingAccount a = new ChequingAccount();
    double deposit = inputCheck("Enter deposit amount: ", input);
    a.setDeposit(deposit);
}

public static double inputCheck(String prompt, Scanner input) {
    boolean userValid = false;
    do {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        double user;
        try {
            user = input.nextDouble();
            if (user < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value cannot be lower than 0");
            }
            userValid = true;
       } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("The value entered is not a number");
            user = inputCheck(prompt, input);
            input.nextLine();
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            user = inputCheck(prompt, input);
       }
         return user;
    } while (!userValid);
}
```

The code works except for the fact that when the method catches the `InputMismatchException`, the code then will loop a bunch of times and breaks the program. I thought adding a doWhile loop would solve the issue but it didn't do anything.

Comment: You're mixing iteration and recursion here. You probably don't want to call `ìnputCheck` in your `catch` blocks

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a loop , you need recursion

```
public static double inputCheck(String prompt, Scanner input) {
        double user;
        try {
            user = input.nextDouble();
            if (user < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value cannot be lower than 0");
            }
            return user;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("The value entered is not a number");
            return inputCheck(prompt, input);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return inputCheck(prompt, input);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your own method from inside; the `inputCheck` method's code calls `inputCheck`. This is a somewhat creative way to write a loop.

You also have... a loop.

So you 2 loops, to do the job that one loop should do. That's why all heck breaks loose here. Pick one: Either use the do/while construct (so do not call yourself), or, don't loop, and call yourself. Either one can be made to work here.

The nextLine stuff is irrelevant and not the problem here (in general don't call that; just set the delimiter properly; call `scanner.useDelimiter("\\r?\\n")` and to get entire lines, use `next()`, not `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of approaches that can work for this – iteration, recursion, exception catching, etc. Your solution is mixing several of them together which makes it harder to understand and also harder to fix.

Here is an example that uses a simple `while` loop, no recursion, no exception catching. It uses [`hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) and, depending on the result, either proceeds to capture the double (by calling [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble())), or prints a message (along with consuming and ignoring whatever non-double token is present by calling [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())).

```
public static double inputCheck(String prompt, Scanner input) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
            double number = input.nextDouble();
            if (number < 0) {
                System.out.println("Value cannot be lower than 0. Please try again.");
            } else {
                return number;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The value entered is not a number. Please try again.");
            input.next(); // consume and ignore whatever non-double input is waiting on the scanner
        }
    }
}
```